# Convert UCS-2 characters to UTF-8 Using C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm pulling some internationalized text from a MS SQL Server 2005 database. As per the defaults for that DB, the characters are stored as UCS-2. However, I need to output the data in UTF-8 format, as I'm sending it out over the web. Currently, I have the following code to convert:

```
SqlString dbString = resultReader.GetSqlString(0);
byte[] dbBytes = dbString.GetUnicodeBytes();
byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, 
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, dbBytes);
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
string outputString = encoder.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

However, when I examine the output in the browser, it appears to be garbage, no matter what I set the encoding to.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
In response to the answers below, the reason I thought I had to perform a conversion is because I can output literal multibyte strings just fine. For example:

```
OutputControl.Text = "カルフォルニア工科大学とチューリッヒ工科大学は共同で、太陽光を保管可能な燃料に直接変えることのできる装置の開発に成功したとのこと";
```

works.  Here, `OutputControl` is an ASP.Net Literal. However,

```
OutputControl.Text = outputString; //Output from above snippet
```

results in mangled output as described above. My hypothesis was that the database's output was somehow getting mangled by ASP.Net. If that's not the case, then what are some other possibilities?

EDIT 2:
Okay, I'm stupid. It turns out that there's nothing wrong with the database at all. When I tried inserting my own literal double byte characters (`材料,原料;木料`), I could read and output them just fine even without any conversion process at all.  It seems to me that whatever is inserting the data into the DB is mangling the characters somehow, so I'm going to look at that.  With my verified, "clean" data, the following code works:

```
OutputControl.Text = dbString.ToString();
```

as the responses below indicate it should.

Comment: What makes you think you need to convert to UTF-8?

Comment: And if you'd answered my question 6 hours ago, err, never mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does essentially the same as:

```
SqlString dbString = resultReader.GetSqlString(0);
string outputString = dbString.ToString();
```

`string` itself is a UNICODE string (specifically, UTF-16, which is 'almost' the same as UCS-2, except for codepoints not fitting into the lowest 16 bits). In other words, the conversions you are performing are redundant.

Your web app most likely mangles the encoding somewhere else as well, or sets a wrong encoding for the HTML output. However, that can't be diagnosed from the information you provided so far.

Comment: It is not redundant if he wants to emit UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @GregS He's doing it at a completely wrong place. I assume he's doing an ASP.NET web app, so HTML output encoding is not a matter for his custom code.

Comment: How is this an answer? It doesn't explain at all why UTF-8 isn't showing up properly.

Comment: @Gabe Quanticle asks what he's missing and he's apparently missing the basics of encodings and strings in .NET. Thus I think my answer is valid.

Comment: I've edited my question to address some of the issues raised here. Specifically, I thought the conversion was necessary because I could output literal strings just fine. If that's not the case, then I'd like some other ideas as to what's wrong.

Comment: @quanticle Did you debug your code to make sure the data is correct just after retrieving from the database?

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny I figured out what the problem is. The problem is the fact that the classic ASP application writing the data is mangling the encoding. That's something that I'm debugging. In the meantime, this answer was quite helpful to me in eliminating problems.

Answer (score 0):

*String* in .net is 'encoding agnostic'.

You can convert *bytes* to *string* using a particular encoding to tell .net how to interprets your bytes.

You can convert *string* to *bytes* using a particular encoding to tell .net how you want your bytes served.

But trying to convert a *string* to another *string* using encodings makes no sens at all.

Comment: This should be a comment; it does not answer the question.